# how to change the key value of an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There are 2 objects 
1)

```
var obj1 = {
id: 1,
firstName: 'someFirst',
lastName: 'someLast',
status: 'active',
}
```

2)

```
var obj2 = {
firstName: 'test',
status: 'disable',
}
```

how can I change the key value of the first object based on the key values of the second object?
Expected result is:

```
obj1 = {
id: 1,
firstName: 'test',
lastName: 'someLast',
status: 'disable',
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: ^ this this is what I meant to ask

Comment: I added the expected result

Answer (score 2):

```
 Object.assign(/*to*/ obj1, /*of*/ obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign(obj1, obj2)` will merge the two objects together, where `obj1` is the base object, and `obj2` will replace any identical properties on the base object with its values.

In your example, this would return

```
{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'text',
  lastName: 'someLast',
  status: 'disable',
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do `newObject = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2)`.

Or use the object spread operator like: `newObject = {...obj1, ...obj2}`.

Do not mutate the original object.